How to determine the actual (not theoretical) maximal size of vector in C++
Is there a way to determine the actual maximal vector size possible at run time (in C++), other than trying vec.resize(size) for different sizes by trail and error?  (vec.max_size() provides only the maximal theoretical limit, see this SO question).
My process goes through vec.reserve(size) fine and then it crashes at vec.resize(size), where size=2^33, so vec.reserve doesn't help much.
Related question: the MacOS activity monitor shows only 14GB RAM "memory used" in its summary on the bottom. See screenshot. That is so strange, because my process (in the top line) is using 64GB RAM. Does it mean that "memory used" is stack only? How can I find the heap memory use?


typically when you request memory you just get a page, nothing else happens. Once you write to it does the actual allocation of memory happens. Once you finally run out of memory then boom, game over.  In theory you can't know how big you can get because you need the biggest contiguous piece of memory available at that moment.

There's no way to know how much memory is available in practice for your vector (or for anything else). In a modern computer the amount of memory available is continuously changing. Then to make things more complicated what you get when you allocate memory is virtual memory not actual memory. It only becomes actual memory when you use it.

Welcome to a phenomenon called "overcommit". When the program asks the operating system for memory, it says "um, sure!" And then when the program tries to use the memory (here, because resize needs to fill it with zeroes), and the operating system can't come up with the memory it promised, it says, "oops, I lied. Sorry." Unix-based systems generally perform overcommit. Windows does not.

The second answer in the duplicated question is better than accepted one.

Side note do NOT use variables or types starting with __  (double undescore) they are intended for internal library/compiler use. For sizes of containers use std::size_t

@PepijnKramer here, __int64_t is a compiler-provided type, not an app type.

@3CxEZiVlQ So vote it up.  Acceptance only means that the accepted resolved the question, it doesn't mean it's the best possible answer.
